# Jackson transient field for concat other field (name + " " + family)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

Is it possible add a transient field to entity that merge another fields?

for example, merge *name* & *family* fields in *fullName* that it's transient;

**P.S**: I use spring-boot & jackson, and if possible guide without custom serialization;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add a getter ?

Something like this :

```
class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;

  @JsonProperty
  public String getFullName() {
    return firstname + " " + lastname;
  }
}
```